# Text Mining: Numbers of raw data to says it's valid

Tags: data-mining, text-mining

Story:
Says one gonna do text mining from a static web pages by crawling them for a semi structured solutions within, the total numbers of pages pulled-out by the crawler is 638. I'm getting asked by prof. if I've enough data to do it and becoming reluctant to change the project subject.

So here's what I'm going to ask, either my google skill have failed me or other.

Simple Question:
**Is 638 of static web pages counted as enough for text mining?**

Info on data structure:

1. Each page is a collection of steps to resolve problem
2. Each of them contains averagely 5 steps
3. Each step has text around 2 line

Do the math and that's approximately around **6380 line of texts**

---

### **Update Info**

**What this text mining is trying to achieve?**

Building an "Automatic Response System" out of it. There're groups of solutions. The goal is to be able to response a small number of solution back to end users, in hope that the replied solution can help the users solved the problem without having to rely on IT personnel.

**Methods used**

*TF-IDF* and *SVM* together

**Data-on-hand**

Static web pages total numbers of 638 page. Each page is a solution to the problem each solution is unique to each other meaning *one-to-one problem-to-solution* relation. But these solution can be grouped together as a kind of solution

**Number of classes**

39 classes

**Number of features**

TBC - It's the number of terms found in corpus (using TF-IDF technique). I'm trying to run a program to get that.

**The Input / Output?**

End-users e-mail message / Solution to a problem.
With this being said meaning that the constructed system must be able to pinpoint a solution (or a set of solutions) from a mere e-mail message.

**
*But this point must be addressed later because it is out of this question context.*

Comment: 638 is **very little**, but depending on your actual problem it *could* be enough. What quality do you get?

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question indeed but i would say the question is broad and pretty hard to say yes or no directly. There are few questions you need to address to find a reasonable answer of your ultimate question.

- Each webpage contains steps to resolve a problem. So, how many problem solutions are given in all 638 webpages?
- If multiple webpages contain solution about a problem, how much they differ? Do all the solutions cover every possible aspects of solving that problem?
- **Important question**: how much accurate system you are aiming to build? More data should results in more accuracy. What should be a reasonable accuracy for your model?

If you split your dataset for training, validation and testing, it seems 638 webpages are not enough. But if those webpages concentrate on small set of problems, then the case can be different. As a designer of your model, you should know what amount of data is required by your model to give sufficiently good performance.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Regarding your points: First, Each web page is a 1:1 problem:solution, Second, due to the first, they're unique to each other. Third, preferably .95, I have no real bases. The system is going to be an Automatic Response System so the input query is e-mail message. That wouldn't go with splitting the training, val, test right? The set of problems is just about 1 product in a company. I aim to use TF-IDF with SVM each keyword found in all docs is a feature or sth like that.

Comment: May be the question is too broad to be a valid question? No one seems to be answering this.

Comment: @Mysteltainn i won't say the question is too broad! i encourage you to update your question and give description as much as possible rather than giving explanation in comment. SVM is a good classifier for text mining. May i know how many classes do you have? do you have 638 individual problem and their solution? during testing what you are aiming to do?

Comment: I've updated part of the question, supply some more info. Is that helpful enough in answering the question?

Comment: @Mysteltainn yes it looks more comprehensive. One comment about the problem- since number of classes is 39, on an average you have 15~16 web pages (i am hoping web pages have lot of contents too) for each class of solution. Its reasonable to do experiments but you should check the performance, otherwise its pretty hard to predict whether the amount of data is sufficient or not.

Comment: For the content, on average, I don't think it  has that much of the content (like 10 lines of sentences each or so --that is from physically lookin, will cal-ed that out later--). I'm going to do some test now, will update the question after that. Thanks.